# Countable intersection of Baire subspaces

Tags: baire-category

I've been lookig around but can't seem to find a way to solve this:
Let X be a Baire space and ${A_n}$ a collection of open sets so that $A= \cap A_n 
 $ is non-empty. Prove that $A$ is a Baire space.
I know it's not hard to prove this if $A$ is dense in X, but i can't seem to find out if it works in general.
Thanks in advance.